# unable to make an image in the corner an responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap to make a landing page and I am having trouble with alignment and responsiveness. I want an image to be in the corner of the screen but when the screen gets smaller it adjusts as well. It's not working with me, it stays in its position. It's the vision.png image i want to move. I tried position relative and absolute, but no luck

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/vision.png" alt="">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <!-- <span class="name">text here</span>-->
                    <!-- <hr class="star-light"> -->
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/Logo.png" alt="">
                    <span class="skills">more text here</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: try using `class="pull-left"`, `class="pull-xs-left"`

Comment: The div `.intro-text` should have `position: absolute` and top, right set to 0, this way it will be in the top right corner of the `col-lg-12` div.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. However, @Bhansa it pulls the div to the left and when the screen gets smaller it no longer resizes the img.

Comment: @LuukSkeur it is moving with the screen but overlaps the other image

Comment: can you provide a minimal example ?

Comment: please create a Bootply where I can see your issue: http://www.bootply.com/new

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, it worked. All I did was add a new div with class="col-3-xs" and put in the image there.

Code:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 vision"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/vision.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/Logo.png" alt="">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <!-- <span class="name">text</span>-->
                    <!-- <hr class="star-light"> -->

                    <!-- <span class="skills">text</span> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```